# Change List externally while being iterated

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
    private static List<String> MyList;

    static void Main()
    {
        MyList = new List<String>();

        var websocketClient = new WebSocket("wss://ws.mysite.com");
        websocketClient.MessageReceived += IterateMyList;

        var updateListTimer = new Timer();
        updateListTimer.Elapsed += UpdateMyList;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void IterateMyList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in MyList)
        {
            //Do Something with the item
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateMyList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add new items to and remove items from MyList. 
    }
```

What happens when Timer tick and new Websocket message events collide?

IterateMyList() will be iterating MyList and UpdateMyList() will be updating it at the same time.

Will I get an exception?

Comment: Look into `ConcurrentBag`

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to insert during iteration, you will raise an exception and get an error saying that you are attempting "read or write protected memory".

To solve this, use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` or [other concurrent collecton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These `Collection` objects are threadsafe. If you do not care about order, I recommend using `ConcurrentBag` for performance reasons.